# Uploading Several of the Most Recent Files in a Folder

Tags: r

I am aware of how to upload the most recent file in a folder using the `mtime` column from the `file.info` function:

```
# Create the example data frame

Name <- c('AAA_2019_01_15.csv', 'AAA_2019_01_16.csv', 'AAA_2019_01_17.csv', 'BBB_2019_01_15.csv', 'BBB_2019_01_16.csv', 'BBB_2019_01_17.csv', 'CCC_2019_01_15.csv', 'CCC_2019_01_16.csv', 'CCC_2019_01_17.csv')
size <- as.numeric(1:9)
isdir <- rep(FALSE, 9)
mode <- rep(666, 9)
mtime <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28", "2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28", "2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28"))
ctime <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28", "2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28", "2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28"))
atime <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28", "2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28", "2019-01-15 18:07:28", "2019-01-16 18:07:28", "2019-01-17 18:07:28"))
exe <- rep("no", 9)
All_Files <- data.frame(size, isdir, mode, mtime, ctime, atime, exe)
All_Files$mode <- as.octmode(All_Files$mode)
rownames(All_Files) <- Name

# Upload the most recent file from the working directory

All_Files <- file.info(list.files(pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE), value = TRUE)
Most_Recent_File <- rownames(All_Files)[which.max(All_Files$mtime)]
Most_Recent_File <- read.table(Most_Recent_File, skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ",", na.strings = "NAN")
```

I'd like to upload the most recent file containing the character string `"AAA"`, the most recent file containing the character string `"BBB"`, and the most recent file containing the character string `"CCC"` using the `mtime` column from  the `file.info` function.

Is there a way to do this without doing a separate uploading step for each character string? For example, can I create a character vector `c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")` and use it to upload the most recent file of each type? In real life, I have a lot more than 3 files to upload, so an efficient way to do this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code of how are you uploading the most recent file using `mtime` column?

Comment: Yes - see above

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way to do things but here is a method using tidyverse and regex patterns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

files <- c('AAA_2019_01_15', 'AAA_2019_01_16', 'AAA_2019_01_17', 
                 'BBB_2019_01_15', 'BBB_2019_01_16', 'BBB_2019_01_17', 
                 'CCC_2019_01_15', 'CCC_2019_01_16', 'CCC_2019_01_17')

dates <- str_extract_all(files, pattern = "[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}", simplify = T) %>% 
  lubridate::ymd()

file_type <- str_extract_all(files, pattern = "AAA|BBB|CCC", simplify = T)


tibble(file_type, dates) %>% 
  mutate(file_names = files) %>% 
  group_by(file_type) %>% 
  arrange(desc(dates)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   file_type [3]
#>   file_type[,1] dates      file_names    
#>   <chr>         <date>     <chr>         
#> 1 AAA           2019-01-17 AAA_2019_01_17
#> 2 BBB           2019-01-17 BBB_2019_01_17
#> 3 CCC           2019-01-17 CCC_2019_01_17
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it:

First, create the character vector of character strings in the file names you wish to get the most recent file of:

```
Unique_Character_Strings_of_Files_to_Upload <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
```

Then, generate the data frame of file information:

```
All_Files <- file.info(list.files(pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE), value = TRUE)
```

Then, generate a list where the first component of the list contains all files containing the character string "AAA", the second component contains all files containing "BBB", and the third component contains all files containing "CCC":

```
List_of_Files <- lapply(Unique_Character_Strings_of_Files_to_Upload, function(x) {List_of_Files <- All_Files[grep(x, rownames(All_Files)), ]})
names(List_of_Files) <- Unique_Character_Strings_of_Files_to_Upload
```

Then, get the most recent file from each component of the list:

```
Most_Recent_Station_Files <- lapply(List_of_Files, function(x) {return(x[which.max(x$mtime), ])})
```

Then, select only the file names from this new list:

```
List_of_Names_of_Files_to_Upload <- lapply(Most_Recent_Station_Files, function (x) rownames(x))
```

Then, convert this new list into a character vector:

```
Names_of_Files_to_Upload <- unlist(List_of_Names_of_Files_to_Upload, use.names = FALSE)
```

Then, upload the files you want:

```
List_of_Files <- lapply(Names_of_Files_to_Upload, function(x) {read.table(x, skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ",", na.strings = "NAN")})
names(List_of_Files) <- Unique_Character_Strings_of_Files_to_Upload
```